# Asus B250 / i3-7300 (Kabylake): VGA works but DVI-D does not work on SOME monitors and TVs

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

I have an Asus B250M-K motherboard with a Core i3-7300 (it has HD 630 inside) and when I connect Samsung 214T to DVI-D there is a black screen. Same with my old TV and HDMI/DVI cable.
I tried several different cables. No luck.

But same configuration works with many other monitors and even with another 214T.

But VGA(d-sub) works correctly for any monitor.

How could it be?

Comment: Do you get the black screen already when you turn on your computer during the initial BIOS boot screen, or does it go blank only once Windows starts to load? What are your BIOS & Windows versions? What is the resolution? Try with all possible devices disconnected.

Comment: @harrymc black screen from the very beginning: I can't even get to BIOS. I tried to disconnect everything except power supply, one ram stick and cpu.

Comment: Which version of BIOS?

Comment: @harrymc latest. I've updated it to latest one from official Asus website

Comment: Do you get any beeps while booting?

Comment: @harrymc yes. It boots normally. I can connect monitor to VGA and it works. But dvi-d does not work,.

Comment: I meant do you get any beeps while booting with DVI when you get a blank screen? You may also open the monitor's on-screen display and see if some parameter has gone weird because of the boot.

Comment: Do you know the difference between DVI - D and DVI-I, and their respective cables that are needed ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

1. Update LCD's firmware, if you can find updates. (For the one it does not work)
2. Get the latest drivers directly from Intel - [HD 630](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-630.html#collapse-object-1)
3. Try to get the correct cable from the [specification](http://www.samsung.com/ie/business/b2b/pdfs/products/displays/professional/sm214t.pdf), you should have a DVI Digital Link : TMDS cable.

What is TMDS ([details](http://www.dvihdmicables.com/dvi_hdmi_faq.htm#tmds))?

**Transition-Minimized Differential Signaling (TMDS)**

> DVI makes use of Transition-Minimized Differential Signaling (TMDS)
>   wherein eight bits of video data are converted to a 10-bit
>   transition-minimized, DC-balanced value.  This value is then
>   serialized and sent to the receiver where the data is de-serialized
>   and converted back to eight bits.
>
> The three TMDS signals needed for RGB make up one TMDS link.  A DVI
>   connector can carry up to two TMDS links providing for better
>   resolutions and timing requirements.  Single TMDS link DVI cables can
>   support resolutions and timings that use a video clock rate of about
>   25-165 MHz.
>
> The following resolutions and timings are supported by a single link
>   DVI cable:
>
> SXGA resolution (1280 x 1024) with 85-Hz refresh rate UXGA resolution
>   (1600 x 1200) with 60-Hz refresh rate SDTV resolutions of 480i, 480p,
>   576i and 576p HDTV resolutions of 720p and 1080i Video clock rates of
>   165-330 MHz on the other hand, are supported only by dual TMDS link
>   DVI cables.  With dual link DVI cables, however, each TMDS link
>   operates at only one-half the frequency of single link DVI.  So the
>   clock and bandwidth is shared by these two links.

That would spell DVI-D dual-link.

You can buy display port cable on one side and DVI-D on other - must be able to do 1440p or 1080p at 144hz.

4. Did you try all options connecting to the graphic card?  The options are     HDMI 1.4, DisplayPort (DP) 1.2, an Embedded DisplayPort (eDP) 1.4 interfaces.  How are you connecting to your DVI-D on your LCD? (Could you list cables you tried?)

**First Edit**

5. Does the other 214T work elsewhere? Maybe it needs to be fixed - [Repairing a samsung syncmaster 214t](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2012/03/14/repairing-a-samsung-syncmaster-214t/)

Comment: Monitor firmware?  Really?  Care to provide a link?

Comment: @Jason: yes, monitors as plenty of TVs, Modems, Owens, Fridges, etc. have firmware.  That should not be a surprise really.  I did not find any updates for this specific model (btw. it is a professional model which would suggest that it could have an update - http://www.samsung.com/us/support/computing/monitors/lcd), otherwise, I would post it.  If you want to have a other samsung one with screenshots - e.g. http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?modelname=S27A850D&homeid=371940&from_osc=&idx=641189&modelcode=LS27A850DS/ZA&

Answer (score 0):

If it works on one 214T but not another 214T, the first thing to try would be resetting the "bad" monitor to factory settings.  Samsung's instructions for this are:

1. Press the Menu button on the monitor. The On Screen Display (OSD) Menu appears.
2. Press the arrow keys, located next to the Menu button, on the monitor to change the menu window until you see the Setup menu.
3. Press the Source button on the monitor to select this window.
4. Reset will automatically highlight. Select Reset by pressing the Source button again.
5. Use the arrow keys to select Yes. As soon as Yes is selected the monitor will reset to factory defaults, you do not have to press anything.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, this implies that the "bad" monitors is partially broken.  You can try to work around the issue by manually setting timing modes for your monitor using something like [Custom Resolution Utility](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).  Here are the timing modes for your monitor (I would start with the last one in the list):

[image: Timing Modes for 214T]